# Legend's font family not set correctly at app's start

Tags: vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

So, I have been working with vue-chartjs and chartjs to create some custom components in a vue3 component library.

My charts work just fine, with one exception. When my Doughnut chart is first rendered in the page, the font family it has is not the one I have set for itself in the options object.
Once I hover the legend or the chart though, the font family gets applied correctly. Also, if I refresh the page the font stays the way it's supposed to be.
Here is my computed options in my DoughnutChart

```
  computed: {
    options () {
      return {
        plugins: {
          'plugin-background': this.background,
          legend: {
            display: this.showLegend,
            position: 'bottom',
            align: 'center',
            onClick: this.onClickLegend,
            onHover: this.onHoverLegend,
            onLeave: this.onLeaveLegend,
            labels: {
              color: '#A6ACBE',
              font: {
                size: 15,
                family: styles.ffamily
              },
              usePointStyle: true,
              pointStyle: 'circle',
              padding: 30,
              pointStyleWidth: 10,
              boxHeight: 7,
              filter: this.filterLegendItems
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: this.enableTooltip,
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: true,
            backgroundColor: '#3D3F48',
            bodyColor: '#FFF',
            bodyFont: { size: 18 },
            borderColor: '#666870',
            borderWidth: null,
            bodyAlign: 'center',
            bodySpacing: 5,
            footerFont: { size: 14 },
            footerColor: '#FFF',
            footerSpacing: 6,
            padding: {
              x: 40,
              y: 20
            },
            caretSize: 7,
            displayColors: false,
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: this.maintainAspectRatio,
        animation: {
          animateRotate: false
        },
        cutout: `${this.width}%`
      }
     }
    },
```

Has someone encountered something similar before? If so, can you please tell me how you solved it?

Thank you so much!